# Read and print from a text file

Tags: java, text-files, bluej, sections

Ok so I'm supposed to be reading and printing from a text file with the code yet every time I run I get a "java.utilNoSuchElementException" on line 31 "grade = in.nextInt();". The current text file is 
2 80 97
5 69 79 89 99 58
7 60 70 80 90 100 0 59

where the first number is the number of scores in each section, each section is supposed to be counted (ie. 1, 2, 3) Anyways one problem at a time. here's the current code.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Prog2
{

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (new File ("test1.txt"));

    int Lowest, Highest, grade = 0;
    float section_average, class_average;
    int count = 0, A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0, F = 0, total_number_of_sections = 0, total_number_of_scores = 0, number = 0;
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        number = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println (in.nextInt());
        number ++;

        while (count < number)
        {
            grade = in.nextInt();
            total_number_of_sections += number;
            total_number_of_scores += grade;
            total_number_of_scores ++;

            count++;


        }

    }
    if (number > 0)
    {
        System.out.println ("Scores for section "+count);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Scores for section 0");
    }
    if (grade >= 90)
    {
        A ++;

    }
    if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
    {
        B ++;

    }
    if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
    {
        C ++;

    }
    if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
    {
        D ++;

    }
    if (grade < 60)
    {
        F ++;

    }
    System.out.println (" ");
    System.out.println ("Scores for section "+count);
    System.out.println ("A's" + A);
    System.out.println ("B's" + B);
    System.out.println ("C's" + C);
    System.out.println ("D's" + D);
    System.out.println ("F's" + F);
    System.out.println ("Lowest Score: ");
    System.out.println ("Highest Score: ");
    System.out.println (" ");
    System.out.println (" ");
    System.out.println ("Total number of sections: " + total_number_of_sections);
    System.out.println ("Total number of scores: " + total_number_of_scores);
    System.out.println ("Class Average: ");



}
```

}

Comment: Dude, you're calling "in.nextInt()" twice in every pass through the loop.  Call it *ONCE*, save the value, and print your saved variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (in.hasNextInt())
{
    count = 0;
    number = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println (in.nextInt());


    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        grade = in.nextInt();
        total_number_of_sections += number;
        total_number_of_scores += grade;
        total_number_of_scores ++;

        if(++count == number ){ break;}


    }

}
```

Comment: it only produced 80 and 79 when entered into my program. Thank you though.